# How to get Span tag text in php?

Tags: php, html, scrape

I am scraping a website in PHP. I have scraped all the required data but I am unable to scrape span tag text.

**Expected Output:** `Apr 20,2017`

```
<span title="" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Posted On">
                                        <i class="calendar rz-calendar"></i>Apr 20, 2017
                                    </span>
$html = file_get_contents($url);
libxml_use_internal_errors( true);
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath( $doc);

$node = $xpath->query( '//span[@data-original-title="Posted ON"]');
```

Answer (score 2):

Problem in your code is `//span[@data-original-title="Posted ON"]` `ON` is not in capitals it is like this `On`

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/779369)

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);


$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML('<span title="" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Posted On">
                                        <i class="calendar rz-calendar"></i>Apr 20, 2017
                                    </span>');
$xpath = new DOMXpath( $doc);
$nodeList = $xpath->query( '//span[@data-original-title="Posted On"]');
foreach($nodeList as $node)
{
    echo trim($node->textContent);
}
```

Comment: Have you checked my post demo? and also do share your HTML as well

Comment: Here is script..! 
<?php 
 ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$html = file_get_contents('https://www.rozee.pk/job/jsearch/q/java');
libxml_use_internal_errors( true);
 $doc = new DOMDocument;
 $doc->loadHTML($html);
 $xpath = new DOMXpath( $doc);
$nodeList = $xpath->query( '//span[@data-original-title="Posted On"]');
    foreach($nodeList as $node)
    {
        echo trim($node->textContent);
    }
?>

Comment: what is the issue in this script?

Comment: @MUmarToor Working on it.

Comment: Ok..! Thank You..! I'll be waiting..!

Comment: @MUmarToor try this https://eval.in/779398 at your system, this site does allow to use file get content, i hope this will be fine